# Find the smallest natural number that satisfy $13^N = 1 \pmod {2013}$

Tags: modules, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, exponentiation, natural-numbers

> **Moderator Note:** This is a current contest question on [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/).

Find the smallest natural number that satisfy:

$$13^N = 1  \pmod {2013}$$

---

My idea is to use the Fermat's little theorem for prime numbers. First I factorize 2013 as 3*11*61

Then i get using the theorem i get:

$$13^{61-1} = 1 \pmod{ 61}\iff 13^{60} = 1 \pmod {61}$$
$$13^{11-1} = 1 \pmod{11}\iff13^{10} = 1 \pmod{11}$$
$$13^{3-1} = 1 \pmod 3\iff 13^{2} = 1 \pmod{3}$$

But because the modulo bases are different I doesn't know how to continue. And even if they were same, the multiplication won't change the modulo base. Is there any way to achieve this?

Actually my idea is to find the smallest natural nubmer that satisfies

$$13^N = 1 \pmod{ 3\cdot 11\cdot 61}$$

Comment: This is a problem taken from Brilliant.org. Please wait for a week before posting your solution - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ok. I was typing mine before I saw your comment!

Comment: [Link](https://brilliant.org/i/YJYAQC/).

Comment: @CalvinLin I didn't take it from there, actually i took it from a local math magazine, but that doesn't mean that they didn't take it from your site.

Comment: One question: why is it important not to help in those Brilliant thing problems? Is that a contest with prices, scholarships or stuff? From the .org thing I gather it is *not* a university or stuff, so who cares? Just asking.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Thanks for the clarification. I certainly don't have copyright over the math ideas involved. You can test out your numerical answer in the link I provided.

Comment: @DonAntonio We are a problem solving site that provides interesting problems for students to improve their problem solving ability. It is free to join, and prizes are awarded to deserving students. Since this is not related to the question, I would prefer to continue this in chat.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $13^{60}\equiv1\pmod{3}$, $13^{60}\equiv1\pmod{11}$, and $13^{60}\equiv1\pmod{61}$ from your equivalences above.

**Hint:** Check factors of $60$.

Answer (score 1):

[Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) will give you a candidate positive exponent. But is that the smallest?

Comment: Good idea, but I think it'll not work for this example, because $phi(2013) = 1200$, which means 1200 is the answer, but Calvin Lin states that the smallest number is less than 1000, which means this doesn't compute the smallest number which satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ where $p$ is prime and $a$ is any integer relatively prime to $p$

If [modulo](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModuloOrder.html)/[Multiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order)  order of $a$ is $ord_pa,$ "as a consequence of [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29),  $ord_pa$ always divides  $\phi(p)=p-1$", we need to test for those powers of $a$ which divides $p-1$

Now,
$$13^1\equiv1\pmod 3\implies ord_3{(13)}=1$$
$$13\equiv2\pmod {11}\implies 11^2\equiv2^2=4,11^5\equiv2^5\equiv-1\implies ord_{11}{(13)}=10$$
$$13^2=169\equiv-14\pmod {61},13^3\equiv(-14)\cdot13\equiv1\implies ord_{61}{(13)}=3$$
So, $ord_{3\cdot11\cdot61}(13)=$lcm$(1,10,3)=30$

Related : [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html)