# Prove that the smallest integer $e$ for which $a^e$ is congruent to $1\bmod p$, where $p$ is prime, divides $p-1$.

Tags: number-theory

Where e is a positive integer and p does not divide a.

A question from Courant's "What is mathematics?".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357667/find-the-smallest-natural-number-that-satisfy-13n-1-pmod-2013/398845#398845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the smallest **positive** integer.  And we want to specify that $p$ does not divide $a$.  If $e=1$ the result is clear, so we may assume that $e\gt 1$.

By the "Division Algorithm" there are non-negative integers $q$ and $r$, with $0\le r\lt e$, such that $p-1=qe+r$.

Thus
$$a^{p-1}=(a^e)^qa^r.$$
By Fermat's Theorem, we have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. And by assumption we have $a^e\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. It follows that $a^r\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Since $r\lt e$, this contradicts the minimality of $e$ unless $r=0$. And $r=0$ implies that $e$ divides $p-1$.

Comment: I was *almost* done typing almost exactly the same answer, but you beat me to it. You have fast fingers!

Comment: I have just finished a cup of coffee. Useful for speed (caffeine is also useful for long distance running). We all have somewhat different styles, so I think that an answer that uses the same basic technique that is expressed differently could be of value to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Such integer is the order of $a$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$. Since the order of an element of a finite group always divides the order of the group by the Lagrange theorem, $e\mid(p-1)$.